# Ubuntu vs Zorin OS

Tags: ubuntu, zorin

I am confused between Zorin and Ubuntu any help would be great, here are some key features I want:

1. Which has more features.(Not required to be pre installed, I can install them)
2. Which supports more apps.
3. Which supports more windows apps.(If we need to install additional things to make them support no issue.)

{*Which is fast*
*Is it like we can run windows application which Zorin can run in Ubuntu at same performance but we need to install something if so no issue*}

Answer (score 2):

Zorin OS is a fork of Ubuntu, so it's based on it. All Ubuntu packages work fine on Zorin OS. The difference between these two distributions is about the look and feel; also, there's a difference in the default packages preinstalled and how they are configured.

According to ZorinOS website: «The Software store allows you to install apps from the Zorin OS & Ubuntu APT repositories, Flathub, and the Snap Store out of the box».

You will be able to use Flathub and Snap on Ubuntu, as well. You will be able to run AppImages in both distributions. And of course, you will be able to install any binary DEB file according your CPU architecture.

Comment: In other words, to explicitly answer 1), 2), 3): both are equal.

Comment: Performance wise?? Cause my laptop is Intel core 2 duo it's very old.

Comment: And it means both can run same amount on windows apps at same speed?

Comment: @Unix thx for help just answer these comments

Comment: @RobinHoodRKA This is a question and answer, not a forum. Comments aren't for discussions, just requests and clarification. Please take the tour to understand how it works: https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour . As courtesy: Any Intel Core 2 Duo is very much old and underpowered therefore the answer is NEITHER. Try AntiX for a very lightweight OS designed to work as best as it possibly can in old hardware.